# Shouldn't the absolute correlation between 2 observations be 1, regardless of the number of features they have?

Tags: correlation

I was going through the "An introduction to statistical learning in R" book and came across this part
[image]

The passage seems to suggest that 2 observations will not necessarily have a correlation of 1 between them if they have more than 2 features. But that doesn't make sense to me. I would think that all the pair-wise correlations (across any 2 features) will have to 1 when we just have 2 observations. I am not sure what the author is trying to say here

Comment: This passage doesn't appear to be "suggesting" anything.  Its assertion is equivalent to the axiom that two distinct points determine a line on which they both lie.  It's difficult to tell what your question is, though, due to some grammatical problems in the last paragraph: could you please read it over and clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the code and see that your intuition is incorrect:

```
set.seed(1234)

x <- matrix(rnorm(30*3), ncol = 3)

cor(t(x))
```

None of the correlations are 1.00

However, if you change it to 30*2 matrix and ncol = 2 then all the correlations are either 1 or -1.

Comment: I think what you are doing is essentially proving my intuition

Comment: No. I am proving that the book is correct and that you are wrong.  You said: "I would think that all the pair-wise correlations (across any 2 features) will have to 1 when we just have 2 observations. " and I showed that that is not the case.